How to prevent multiprocessing spawn from using an edited python script?
I am running multiprocessing in Python with start method 'spawn'. I have the following code:
import time
import multiprocessing

def print_something():
    print("1")

def main():

    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

    while True:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_something)
        process.start()
        process.join()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When I run this piece of code, python will print '1' every second. My problem is the following. I start running the main() function and let it run on the background. If I edit the above code, let's say I change print("1") to print("2"), and I save the code, the background function will start printing "2" instead of "1". This means that saving the code is not safe: if I for example save bugged code, the background function will crash.
The multiprocessing start method influences the result. If I use 'fork', it will always print '1' even after editing and saving the code. However, both 'spawn' and 'forkserver' uses the updated script, instead of the script at the moment of starting main().
What I want is to safely edit and save the code without it affecting background processes, while using start method 'spawn'. How can I achieve this?

The obvious and trivial solution is to edit a different copy of the file. If you are not using Git already, probably start there.

@tripleee That sounds like a fine solution if I have only one background process running. But I want to have up to 8 of these scripts running, each with their own version of the code. Copying then quickly get unmanageable.
I don't see how Git helps either. Sure I can start main() with a specific commit, but if I then checkout a new branch, the spawned processes will use the new branch code.

Huh? You check out the historical version you want to run. Checking out eight working copies in /tmp (or just one, if you don't need them to be independent) and then cleaning up when you are done sounds very reasonable to me.

Ah I see. So one workaround to copy the whole codebase to a new directory, then run the script from there. I prefer a pythonic solution, but if that is not possible I guess I can use that for now.
